# Bash conditional input

Tags: bash

Writing a bash script which **might receive** an *optional parameter* and run.

The code looks like:

`docker-compose exec foo ./manage.py test integration_tests.tests$@ --noinput`

If the parameter is specified the path should be `integration_tests.tests.path.to.module`. If not `integration_tests.tests`

Notice the dot after `tests`.

### Question

How to modify `integration_tests.tests$@` to handle this properly? Smth like `integration_tests.tests${@:-.@}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `${1:+.}`. The `+` means that if the variable is set, use this text, otherwise nothing.

```
docker-compose exec foo ./manage.py test "integration_tests.tests${1:+.}$1" --noinput
```

*Update*: Missed quotes in case `$1` has spaces or such.